# Show default option value after AJAX and JQUERY function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX function that runs when a new option is selected. The HTML looks like this:

```
<select class="event_change" id="event_change" name="event">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Event</option>
    <option id="1|2|3">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Andy my AJAX / JQuery looks like this:

```
$('.event_change').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).find(':selected')[0].id;
    if (confirm("Confirm")== true){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'event_docs.php',
        data: {'id': id},
        success: function () {
        alert("Success!")
        }
    });
    $(this).find(':selected')[0].remove();
}
});
```

The AJAX and JQuery works perfectly in that the ID value of the selected option is sent as a POST value and then that option is removed from the selection.

What I am struggling to figure out is how to reset the default option to one initially set as selected in the HTML.

I've had a good dig around and did think I can create a new option with the content needed but then on the dropdown I would have two disabled options if that makes sense?

Does anybody know of a way to reset the select options and show the original selected one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the default is always the first option you can just set the selected index to 0.

```js
$('.event_change').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).find(':selected')[0].id;
    if (confirm("Confirm")== true){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'event_docs.php',
        data: {'id': id},
        success: function () {
        alert("Success!")
        }
    });
    this.selectedIndex = 0;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="event_change" id="event_change" name="event">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Event</option>
    <option id="1|2|3">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you, good knowledge for future use as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('[name=event]').val('');` to reset the options.

You don't have to remove the :selected selector, so just replace `$(this).find(':selected')[0].remove();` by `$('[name=event]').val('');`

Comment: This is also spot on thanks. However I do need to keep the remove function in as once a user has selected then confirmed the option it needs to be removed so not in the list anymore.